# Add favicon for bookmark bar from drag n drop javascript link

Tags: javascript

i'am trying to add favicon for bookmark bar, best way is to see what happens is try to bookmark markerr.com "easy translate" button to your bookmark... And you will note that there is no favicon for "Translate"

Any suggestion how to add favicon to this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `favicon.ico` file is always located at the root of the web server (i.e. `http://markerr.com/favicon.ico`) and the browser implicitly requests this. Since the browser is *implicitly* requsting this, the only way to provide parameters is to change the domain name (i.e. favicon now located at `http://translate.markerr.com/favicon.ico`). I don't think this has anything to do with JavaScript